# How to get limits for azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

There are some limits for creating resources in an azure subscription, as outlined in the Azure documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits

How to programmatically get the limits from azure cli/sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few commands to check Resource Limits

1. `az --version` helps you to find the installed version.
2. `az login` to log in to Azure.
3. `az network list-usages --location [--subscription]` List the number of network resources in a region that is used against a subscription quota.

For more information, you can check this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/check-usage-against-limits#azure-cli).

Here are few commands to check Subscription Limits

1. `az account show` To view which Azure Subscription.
2. `az account list` To view a list of all the Azure Subscriptions.
3. `az account set --subscription "Company Subscription"` To set the Azure Subscription you want to target.

For more information, you can refer to this [Blog](https://build5nines.com/azure-cli-2-list-set-azure-subscription/)